# Where are custom system shortcuts stored in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, path, system-preferences

I have my personal custom shortcuts for different apps and I would like to have them synced across devices, but I can't find the file where Mac OS X stores them.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where are these shortcuts? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: I searched a bit but couldn't find anything helpful. Also this [unanswered post at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512326/) discourages too

Comment: yeah... I have already seen that thread... that's why I tried to put this on mac related forum... but apparently we are not getting luck :)

Answer (score 3):

They're stored in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` in the following format:

```
NSUserKeyEquivalents = {
        "System Preferences…" = "@~,";
    };
```

Methodology: ran `sudo opensnoop | grep '.plist'` in order to see `plist` files being accessed while modifying the settings in System Preferences. (Note: on El Capitan, SIP prevents running `opensnoop` by default. [It can be enabled](http://jimtechstuff.blogspot.ca/2015/10/dtrace-broken-under-el-capitan.html) by enabling `dtrace`.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, shortcuts for each application are stored under `NSUserKeyEquivalents` in the application's plist file, e.g. `com.apple.Preview.plist`. This is true for (at least some) non-Apple applications too, e.g. `com.omnigroup.OmniOutliner5.plist.`